# Powershell calling function with argument as string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call `Get-ChildItem` function from custom function. The problem is the arguments to the function can be dynamic.

```
function Test {
    Get-ChildItem $Args
}
```

When I try

```
Test .\    //this works as Path is taken as default argument value
Test .\ -Force //this doesn't work as expected as it still tries to consider entire thing as Path
Test -Path .\ -Force //same error
```

How to `wrap around function` and `pass the arguments as it's`?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem @Args`

Comment: @PetSerAl Waaay better than IEX hack, I've forgot that one can splat arrays. Should be an answer.

Comment: @PetSerAl, can you post your answer? I believe this is better than IEX. and IEX doesn't support `space separated arguments`. This supports everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$args` is an array of arguments, and passing it to the `Get-ChildItem` wouldn't work, as you've noticed. The PowerShell-way for this would be the [Proxy Command](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/07/18/build-a-better-powershell-function.aspx).

For a quick-and-dirty hack, you can use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
function Test {
    Invoke-Expression "Get-ChildItem $Args"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-Expression will be difficult to work with because what's been passed as strings will need quoting all over again when expressed in a string. ProxyCommand is the better way as beatcracker has suggested.

There are a few alternatives for fun and interest. You might splat PSBoundParameters, but you will need to declare the parameters you expect to pass.

This is an incomplete example in that it will easily get upset if there are duplicate parameters (including common parameters if you set CmdletBinding on the function Test).

```
function Test {
    dynamicparam {
        $dynamicParams = New-Object Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        foreach ($parameter in (Get-Command Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Values) {
            $runtimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter(
                $parameter.Name,
                $parameter.ParameterType,
                $parameter.Attribtes
            )
            $dynamicParams.Add($parameter.Name, $runtimeParameter)
        }

        return $dynamicParams
    }

    end {
        Get-ChildItem @psboundparameters
    }
}
```